flutter_local_notifications does not work with the custom notification icon only for the Android release build; I must be missing something
I have integrated flutter_local_notifications with my app and it was working great with the iOS and Android during the development. However, I noticed that the Android app that was released doesn't show the notification. It seems to be caused by the custom notification icon I set.
const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_notification');

The logcat that looks relevant:
08-30 08:33:23.291  2423  2423 E Icon    : Unable to load resource 0x7f06007f from pkg=com.example.package
08-30 08:33:23.291  2423  2423 E Icon    : android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.package:drawable/ic_notification with resource ID #0x7f06007f
08-30 08:33:23.291  2423  2423 W StatusBarIconView: No icon for slot com.example.package/0x79716; Icon(typ=RESOURCE pkg=com.example.package id=0x7f06007f)

If I replaced the ic_notification with @mipmap/ic_launcher, everything works as expected.
I created the icon following the official instruction and it placed ic_notification.png in my Android project as follows:
android/app/src/main/res/
├── drawable
│   ├── ic_launcher_background.xml
│   └── launch_background.xml
├── drawable-anydpi
│   └── ic_notification.xml
├── drawable-hdpi
│   └── ic_notification.png
├── drawable-mdpi
│   └── ic_notification.png
├── drawable-v21
│   └── launch_background.xml
├── drawable-xhdpi
│   └── ic_notification.png
├── drawable-xxhdpi
│   └── ic_notification.png

I was thinking it was all I have to do but what am I missing? I'm guessing it should be something related to my build configuration as the issue is observed only on the release build though.

for notification icon image must be transparent. issue might be due to the background
https://www.remove.bg/upload
upload you image here remove background and then try
also you can follow this thread
notification icon doesn't show in flutter android app local_notification_flutter

Thank you for the answer. However, I don't think the issue is the icon itself. As I mentioned I created a notification icon with Image Asset Studio in Android Studio as described in the developer document. So I feel the issue is more like WHERE the icon should be placed or I miss some configuration such as AndroidManifest, etc.
